# Moderator input needed

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I got down voted on a 2 year old post, without giving any reason.

[How a java app read its own JNLP path programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343490/how-a-java-app-read-its-own-jnlp-path-programmatically/31654680#31654680)

I work very hard to gather pertinent information and helpful links before answering questions. These kinds of down voting is cheap and slap in my face.

I am requesting moderators to take action against this kind of behavior and rectify the situation.

Comment: *I got down voted on a 2 year old post*. Well, you are not gonna like the votes on this post either.

Comment: If you're that worried about reputation on Stack, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Before people use the meta effect.. please do not downvote OPs answer in question unless it's wrong. Downvoting because of this question alone is wrong.

Comment: It's quite obvious what has happened. Someone else has posted an answer and that answer has prompted someone to see the question on their radar. (Maybe it was the OP, although doubtful.). They have then reviewed the answers and downvoted accordingly. Also don't take votes so personal (I know we tend to) but it's about the content of the answer. Anyone at anytime can downvote an answer even if it's _old_.

Comment: I haven't and wont vote on it, but... it appears as though your answer isn't answering the question asked. that very well could be a reason to downvote.

Comment: If an answer doesn't answer the question, isn't it supposed to attract enough downvotes to either motivate the poster to remove or remedy their answer, or at least let people clearly know that the information presented does not answer the question?  Should the age of a question - two years or no - really have any bearing on this process?

Comment: It would be good idea to edit your answer first to actually provide an answer to the question before requesting any additional attention to the post. "No, you can't, do ... instead", "Yes you can by ..., but better ... instead" are answers; what currently is in linked post does not have actual answer part. Note: complaining that you "...don't quite understand the use case, why you want to start another instance within java" should be either comment or removed.

Comment: People get downvoted daily on SO, that's quite a lot of slapping.

Comment: Moderators can't see individual votes, nor would you want us to. We also can't change votes (again, you wouldn't want us to have this ability). There's no way we can tell whether a single vote was "legitimate" or not. Now, someone attacking another person with a series of timed, targeted votes, that's a different matter. However, we're not talking about that here.

Answer (score 33):

Moderators certainly aren't going to look into a single random downvote on an obscure answer. We have better things for them to do.

> without giving any reason

No reason is required. If it were, the site would make you provide one.

Just take the feedback that someone who came across the answer found it "not useful." Ask yourself why that may be. Is it technically accurate? Clear? Complete enough? Not just duplicating what another answer (there or on a duplicate question) has already said?

If you don't come up with an answer to why someone may have found it not useful, meh, don't sweat it. If, in general, you're providing useful answers, that will be clear to the community. Individual posts aren't really important.

Answer (score 4):

Users aren't required to comment on downvotes. This has been discussed for all of time, please search for some past discussion on it. Bottom line: users will never be required to comment on downvotes. That doesn't mean there wasn't a reason for it though, that also doesn't mean I, or any other user, knows what that reason was aside from the assumption it followed standard voting outlook (useful, helpful, etc.).

That said, here is what happened in your specific situation. 9 hours ago (at the time of me writing this) an answer was posted to the question where your answer was. The new answer triggered the late answer review queue. Several users reviewing the late answer also then reviewed the post as a whole, bringing new attention to it. One of them decided to edit the title of the post to fix a spelling error which bumped it to the active page, bringing new attention to it.

Of the users who viewed the post as a result of the queue or being bumped to the front page, 5 of them decided your answer warranted a downvote. Why? I don't know. I am not an expert in that technology and as a result I did not vote because I am unsure of the answer's usefulness, and also because voting on content shown in meta feels like dogpiling and in these instances seems counter productive.

However, those users found your post *organically*, which is to say they saw it from a content based path: either a queue or the active page. Their votes were theirs to cast and there is absolutely nothing a moderator should do in this situation.

If your answer did not warrant the downvotes, then that is unfortunate. On the other hand, the OP didn't think it solved their problem, it sat at 0 votes for over a year, and while it explains some process of starting a java app from jnlp, it doesn't seem to address how to read the path in the app.

So, for these reasons and circumstances, that is how your answer came to be downvoted. Don't take it personally, it wasn't someone following *you* specifically; attention was brought to the content, and the content was voted on.

---

<sub>*For reference*:</sub>
<sub>Post: [How can a Java application read its own JNLP path programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31343490/1026459)</sub>
<sub>Review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15631068</sub>
<sub>Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31343490/revisions</sub>
<sub>Answer timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31654680/timeline</sub>

Comment: Great analysis. One thing: *"Of the users who viewed the post as a result of the queue or being bumped to the front page, 5 of them decided your answer warranted a downvote."* As of when the OP asked this question, the answer was only at +0/-1. (I happened to look at it contemporaneously, having been part of the group who migrated the question.) That quickly went up, but I'm guessing meta effect rather than organically. :-)